# How to get 5 day Yahoo weather forecast

Tags: php, xml, rss, yahoo-weather-api

I've been working on a weather feed for my website.

I'm currently only able to get forecasts for the next 2 days. I want forecasts for the next 5 days.

Here's my code:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$locationstr = "http://api.locatorhq.com/?user=MYAPIUSER&key=MYAPIKEY&ip=".$ipaddress."&format=xml";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($locationstr);

$city = $xml->city;

switch ($city)
{
    case "Pretoria":
        $loccode = "SFXX0044";

        $weatherfeed = file_get_contents("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=".$loccode."&u=c");
        if (!$weatherfeed) die("weather check failed, check feed URL");
        $weather = simplexml_load_string($weatherfeed);

        readWeather($loccode);
        break;
}

function readWeather($loccode)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=".$loccode."&u=c");

    $channel = $doc->getElementsByTagName("channel");

    $arr;
    foreach($channel as $ch)
    {
        $item = $ch->getElementsByTagName("item");
        foreach($item as $rcvd)
        {
            $desc = $rcvd->getElementsByTagName("description");

            $_SESSION["weather"] = $desc->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to direct your attention to the lines that query for the weather:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=".$loccode."&u=c");

// url resolves to http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=SFXX0044&u=c in this case
```

Searching google, I found [this link](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Yahoo-Weather-5-day-Forecast/1228762478000-84d25277-b9c6-35c0-8c54-c487a5093090) which suggested I use this url instead:

```
$doc->load("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/SFXX0044_c.xml");
```

While this also works and I see a 5 day forecast in the XML file, I still only see 2 days forecast on my site.

I have a feeling this is because I'm leveraging the `channel` child element found in the RSS feed, while the XML feed has no such child element.

If anyone can provide any insight here, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Why are you loading it with `SimpleXML`, not using it and then loading it again with `DOMDocument`?  Personally I feel `SimpleXML` is easier for parsing RSS feeds but either way you should use one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get for asking questions too early...

As I was looking over my code again, I noticed that I had the yahooapis URL referenced twice: once in the switch, and again in readWeather.

Having removed the redundant reference and updating the url as per the thread mentioned, I see that it does work now.

See updated code for reference:

```
switch ($city)
{
    case "Pretoria":
        $loccode = "SFXX0044";

        readWeather($loccode);
        break;
}

function readWeather($loccode)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/".$loccode."_c.xml");

    $channel = $doc->getElementsByTagName("channel");

    $arr;
    foreach($channel as $ch)
    {
        $item = $ch->getElementsByTagName("item");
        foreach($item as $rcvd)
        {
            $desc = $rcvd->getElementsByTagName("description");

            $_SESSION["weather"] = $desc->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```